# Possibility to use Tomato by Shibby VPN Client to link with Cisco Easy Connect VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have a question of feasibility and would like to know your point.

I have a Cisco RV325 configured with Easy VPN enabled at a first place. There, there is also a voip central.

I have a WiFi phone I would like to use in two different places (different WAN connection).

To me, the best solution I can use is to create a VPN Tunnel between the houses.

Do you think a little Netgear WNR3500Lv2 flashed with Tomato By Shibby latest version could be used to do this tunnel ?

Thanks.